# MS Word Legacy Form Text Form Field restrict editing except changing the font size

Tags: ms-word, textformfield

[image]

Under restrict editing, users can only add or delete words. Can I allow users to change the font size only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to write a kluge to display a font size userform, then unprotect the form, set the font size and reprotect. This sample does not include the userform:

```
Dim FontSize As Long

Sub SetSize()
    FontSizeDlg.Show    'Dialog allows user to choose size, which sets the FontSize variable
    With ActiveDocument
        If .ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then
            .Unprotect
        End If
        .Bookmarks("Name").Range.Font.Size = FontSize
        .Bookmarks("Class").Range.Font.Size = FontSize
        If .ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
            .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, noreset:=True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 'FontSizeDlg.Show' returns the run-time error '424': 'Object required' and it seems that I can't look for it in VBA codes.

Comment: As I mentioned, this code sample does _not_ include the userform. You'll have to create that and call it _FontSizeDlg_.

Comment: Thanks, John! It points me to the use of a UserForm which I haven't been aware of.